# passing HTML form input to JavaScript to BaaS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store user HTML input field values in a BaaS (Backendless). Using *fixed* values in the .js script and executing it upon *page load*, I am able to successfully store the fields (`apiEndpoint`, `apiSecretkey`, `emailAddress`) to the `Request` table:

```
function Request(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.apiEndpoint = args.apiEndpoint || "";
    this.apiSecretkey = args.apiSecretkey || "";
    this.emailAddress = args.emailAddress || "";
}

var requestObject = new Request( {
apiEndpoint: "https://api.foo.com/",
apiSecretkey: "foo",
emailAddress: "foo@foo.com",
});

var savedRequest = Backendless.Persistence.of( Request ).save( requestObject );
```

What I would like to do is store *variables* (and on button click rather than page load). Here's my very basic HTML form:

```
<head>
    <script src="libs/backendless.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="endpoint"><br>
        <input type="text" name="secretkey"><br>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="button" onclick="________" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

and `app.js` with variables:

```
function Request(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.apiEndpoint = args.apiEndpoint || "";
    this.apiSecretkey = args.apiSecretkey || "";
    this.emailAddress = args.emailAddress || "";
}

var endpoint = document.getElementsByName("endpoint").value,
    secretkey = document.getElementsByName("secretkey").value,
    email = document.getElementsByName("email").value;

var requestObject = new Request( {
apiEndpoint: endpoint,
apiSecretkey: secretkey,
emailAddress: email,
});

var savedRequest = Backendless.Persistence.of( Request ).save( requestObject );
```

Nothing happens when I click the Submit button. For `onclick=""` in my form, I have tried `Request()`, `JavaScript: Request()`, `Backendless.Persistence.of( Request ).save( requestObject );`.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JavaScript that you pasted in is the only JavaScript on the page then it's very likely that it's all being executed on page load (which is why hardcoded values work, they exist at load time). What you want is to execute the code when the submit button is clicked. You can do that by assigning a value to the `onsubmit` attribute, then create a function in your JavaScript called `sendData`.

**EDIT**

Looks like I messed up the function by forgetting to include the actual call to your BaaS. Here's a snippet demonstrating how this should work. You definitely don't want an `onclick` handler assigned to your submit button.

Also, `getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` not an `Element`, so the `value` property is not defined, you'd have to iterate through the list or access the first element. `getElementById` is better if you don't mind using ids.

```js
function Request(args) {
    args = args || {};
    this.apiEndpoint = args.apiEndpoint || "";
    this.apiSecretkey = args.apiSecretkey || "";
    this.emailAddress = args.emailAddress || "";
}


function sendData () {
  var endpoint = document.getElementById("endpoint").value,
    secretkey = document.getElementById("secretkey").value,
    email = document.getElementById("email").value;

  var requestObject = new Request( {
    apiEndpoint: endpoint,
    apiSecretkey: secretkey,
    emailAddress: email,
  });
  alert('apiEndpoint = ' + requestObject.apiEndpoint + '\n' +'apiSecretkey = ' + requestObject.apiSecretkey + '\n' + 'emailAddress = ' + requestObject.emailAddress);
  //var savedRequest = Backendless.Persistence.of( Request ).save( requestObject );
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form onsubmit="sendData()">
        <input type="text" id="endpoint"><br>
        <input type="text" id="secretkey"><br>
        <input type="text" id="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I created the function and tried `<form onsubmit="sendData()">` with  `<input type="submit">` but no luck :/ I also tried using `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByName`.

Comment: @Eric, sorry I messed up the `sendData` function by omitting the Backendless call. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used `getElementById` and wrapped the call in a function and the data successfully stored in the table!